# Command line permissions in Mac

Tags: macos, ubuntu, mac, terminal, homebrew

I’ve tried to install yarn using Homebrew and because the brew don’t have the permission to write I’ve written this command line in Terminal $sudo chown -R $(whoami) *
After this command my Mac is hanging, how can i give the permission back

Comment: Is the command still running? If yes, have you tried to simply cancel it (CTRL C)?

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to just go to System Preferences -> Security and Privacy -> Privacy -> Developer Tools -> Terminal. Before you check the terminal you might have to click the lock and then type in your password or touch ID.